# Show javascript variable in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a function that, when the form is submitted, shows a pop up. In that pop up i have  a link `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url 'enviado' name=? mail=?  }}">Join</a>`

I want to pass my js variables there. This is my code:

My js:

```
document.querySelector('#elform').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

    fetch("", {

      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        mail: document.querySelector('#email').value,
        name: document.querySelector('#name').value
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
          popup_content('show');
       
        }
    });
}
  });
})
```

My html, the pop up content:

```
<div id="popup_content_wrap" style='display:none'>
      <div align="center" id="popup_content">
          <center>
               <p>Welcome</p>

                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url 'enviado' name=? mail=?  }}">Join</a>

              <a align="right" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="popup_content('hide')">Go back</a>
          </center>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the href using javascript.  Put this in your last .then.  You'll need to add a selector to the "join" link.

```
let mail = document.querySelector('#email').value;
let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;

document.querySelector('#joinlink').href = `/enviado?name=${ name }&mail=${ email }`
```

You can build the url using a template literal or with any other method.